# How to get a custom error message from Web Api to jQuery.ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, jqxhr

This code uses the Microsoft Web Api Http stack and jQuery.

How do I get a custom error message, created by an *HttpError* parameter to *CreateErrorResponse()*, displayed by jQuery's *deferred.fail()*?

An example of creating an error response for test purposes in an ApiController:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Region region)
{
    var error = new HttpError("Failure to lunch.");
    return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
               HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
               error);
}
```

Here's a cut-down client that's trying to find the error message to display, "Failure to lunch.".

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/region',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(region)
})
.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + ": " + jqXhr.responseText);
});
```

What will be displayed is:

> "error: Internal Server Error: {full stack here}"

What I want instead is:

> "Failure to lunch."

Comment: Do you mean "failure to launch" not lunch

Comment: @KevinHolditch I was hungry!

Comment: so am I now I've read your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could parse the `responseText` string and then use the `Message` property:

```
.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('application/json') > -1) {
        // only parse the response if you know it is JSON
        var error = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
        alert(error.Message);
    } else {
        alert('Fatal error');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is where I'm getting confused. jqXhr.responseText.Message has the error message from the InternalServerError ("An error has occurred."), not the custom message I put into HttpError.

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer. You should use `alert(error.Message)` instead of `alert(error).Message`. The Message property will contain the text `Failure to lunch.`. I have just tested it and it worked fine. Could you show the value of `jqXhr.responseText`?

Comment: I was confused, it turns out, because my test case here was throwing *another* InternalServerError exception which was being returned before my CreateErrorResponse code was being hit. The Web API will comfortably cope with this in the absence of any try..catch code. You're quite right, the Message property is what I needed.